# Raspbian Buster Lite splash screen instead of boot messages on Pi 3 Model B (a02082)

Tags: raspbian-buster

I would like to hide/replace the initial boot messages and a dark screen with a splash screen.

I am booting Raspberry Pi into Kiosk mode with Chromium Browser auto starting NodeJS server running ReactJS on the frontend. I am really happy with the setup. The only part is that at the boot it is showing boot messages and then around 12 seconds while the chromium loads and server start there is just a blank black screen. It would be much friendlier if at that time a splash screen is shown.

I have spent whole day following different guides that are either solving this problem for NOOBS or Raspbian Jessie but there are no new ones for the Raspbian Buster Lite.

debian version = 10

Thank you for your help with this I am aware that plenty more people will have the same question.

Answer (score 3):

This was "stolen" from https://yingtongli.me/blog/2016/12/21/splash.html with just one correction. In my system it shows a black screen for about 5 seconds before showing the splash image.

Disable the Raspberry Pi ‘color test’ by adding the line disable_splash=1 to /boot/config.txt.

Disable the Raspberry Pi logo in the corner of the screen by adding logo.nologo to /boot/cmdline.txt.

Disable the various bits of output from the kernel and friends by adding consoleblank=0 loglevel=1 quiet to /boot/cmdline.txt and replace “console=tty1” with “console=tty3”

Disable the login prompt by running as root:

```
systemctl disable getty@tty1
```

Install fbi, the framebuffer image viewer, by running as root:

```
apt install fbi
```

Create the file /etc/systemd/system/splashscreen.service with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Splash screen
DefaultDependencies=no
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fbi -d /dev/fb0 --noverbose -a /opt/splash.png
StandardInput=tty
StandardOutput=tty

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

Replace /opt/splash.png with the path to the splash screen image as appropriate.

Enable the service to be run at boot by running as root:

```
systemctl enable splashscreen
```

Comment: Using the above, the splash screen is displayed (which is great) but will stay on and not disappear when the desktop should appear.

Comment: It does only one part of the goal. First basic debian splash is shown. After, my specific one is shown with 
- progress bar => nice rendering
- gif on bottom right => not user friendly

Comment: This didn't work for me (screen remains black). I'm using Debian Bookworm.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try this. I'm using Raspberry Pi Zero 2W and tried to apply this, however booting is just stopped and system freezing after showing splash png.